# Two class files created in Apache for 1 Java File

Tags: java, apache

When i compiled VisaTaxDetailsDAOHibernate java file in tomcat there were two class files created named as 1)VisaTaxDetailsDAOHibernate.class 
                 2)VisaTaxDetailsDAOHibernate$3.class 
Why two files were created can anyone tell me

Answer (score 1):

The `$3` one will be a compiled anonymous inner class.

Comment: moreover if you have VisaTaxDetailsDAOHibernate$3 there must be at least VisaTaxDetailsDAOHibernate$1 and VisaTaxDetailsDAOHibernate$2

Answer (score 1):

`VisaTaxDetailsDAOHibernate` has an anonymous inner class defined in it. Right? (More than one?)

That `$3` is the class file of that anonymous inner class. Since you did not give it a name ("anonymous") the compiler gives one.

(If you have an inner class (with name), that would be Outer$Inner.class.)